# preventing user input on share button?

Tags: php, facebook

im using the following code to share content on facebook-

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=325675344144789&link=<?=$station_info->link?>&
  picture=<?=$station_info->img_url?>&
  name=<?=$station_info->title?>&
  caption=<?=$station_info->link_caption?>&
  description=<?=$station_info->message?>&
  message=<?=$station_info->title?>&
  redirect_uri=<?=current_url()?>">
```

but the user is being presenter with a box in the dialog for input "say something about this" i need to prevent this if possible.. is there a url parameter that i am missing- i thought it was the message parameter but this is not being used.

i would like the status to be pulled from my db or not have the option- i want to control the content that the user share.

**further clarification**

the workflow of this process is- the user is presented with the post as in a kind of wysiwg format- then they have the option to post it from a anchor tag link- from a fb button

Comment: And what would you like to happen instead?

Comment: See papaiatis's answer, you can't prevent that (unless you use the LIKE button).

Comment: The `message` option is indeed not working with `<a>` tags. Try the `Graph API` as well to create a share dialog. The method is: `/PROFILE_ID/feed`. This one also accepts a `message` parameter that might work. More details: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

Comment: Why would you want to do this? It seems insane to want include a share option without wanting the user to actually share..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taken from [facebook policy](http://developers.facebook.com/policy/)

You must not pre-fill any of the fields associated with the following products, unless the user manually generated the content earlier in the workflow: Stream stories (user_message parameter for Facebook.streamPublish and FB.Connect.streamPublish, and message parameter for stream.publish), Photos (caption), Videos (description), Notes (title and content), Links (comment), and Jabber/XMPP.

Comment: the user is shown what the post is- then its their choice to post it or not. this action occurs further down the workflow

Comment: The idea is user comments should be exactly that ... their thoughts. There are enough tools to present YOUR content.

Comment: can you elaborate on the tools then- am looking for something on to enable sharing- but not have to play around with open graph meta tags

Comment: Your link should be fine. The point is you can't hide or prefill the user message. I think it was possible several months ago but Facebook chaged this. Not sure if the message parameter is even usable anymore.

Comment: although not what i was hoping for i will accept your response

Answer (score 1):

**Display Modes**

Platform Dialogs are all built to seamlessly run in a variety of display contexts on both the web and mobile.

`page:` By default, dialogs run in full-page mode with a Facebook header and footer. This is appropriate for apps that do a full-page redirect in a normal desktop/laptop web browser.

`popup:` For use in a browser popup no bigger than 400px by 580px. Use this display type to maintain context for the user while on an external website.

`iframe:` Display the dialog in a lightbox iframe on the current page. Because of the risk of clickjacking, this is only allowed for some certain dialogs, and requires you to pass a valid access_token.

Source: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/#display

As you can see, there is no such option to prevent the dialog to open. Use the `Facebook Like` button if you don't want to open any dialog but still allow the user to share/post/like a link on his/her wall.